Noise in ADC PIN
for signal conditioning before feeding it to the ADC of a microcontroller, I have the circuit shown in the image below. The 12V comes from an external source, and my goal is to measure this voltage using the voltage divider and the op-amp.
The op-amp's power supply of 3.3V is also used to power my microcontroller. The issue is as follows: when I tried to read the ADC with this circuit, the measurements varied too much. So, I decided to use an oscilloscope and check the ADC_OUT signal. Indeed, we had a ripple of 300 to 500 mV, something that was not possible to measure; this was an unwanted noise.
After several investigations and circuit testing, I found a way to reduce the noise, and the solution was to remove the 4.7uF capacitor C41 and the 0.1uF capacitor C42.
This significantly reduced the noise, but I wanted to know why. Why did these capacitors cause noise? It's worth noting that before using each component, I made sure to measure them with a precise bench multimeter.
In summary, I want to know why these capacitors were generating noise. I appreciate your response in advance.




What noise did you observe with C41 installed and C42 removed?

This LM321 datasheet suggests (on page  9) that the maximum capacitance which should be directly connected to the output is only 50pF. You've exceeded that by a factor of 2000 with your 0.1uF C42. As a result the opamp is probably oscillating.

Note that the LM321 data sheet specifies the common mode input range topping out at Vcc - 1.5, so 3.3V supply is pretty borderline for what you're trying to do.

Most op-amps are unstable with capacitive load.
You cannot directly connect a 100nF capacitor to an output of op-amp and expect it to work. That's about 1000 to 10000 times too large.
If there is capacitance, like a discrete capacitor or just some kind of capacitive load like few meters of cable, you generally are required to add a series resistor to op-amp output, to isolate it from the capacitance it is driving.
Also note that generally the input pin of a microcontroller ADC is also switching a few pF capacitor momentarily to the pin to sample the voltage, and many op-amps can't handle being sampled with the ADC capacitor either.
It really is best to just put a sensible resistor value of few hundred ohms in place of the 0R, regardless of any external capacitance being put there.

I concur with @Justme - Just change R48 to something reasonable, eg something greater than 47 ohms and less than 10k.
